# Максимальное значение из двоичной системы С++

Tags: c++

[Задача "Циклические сдвиги"](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/27)

Вообщем написал код, но не все тесты прошли.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n;     //исходное число
    cin >> n;  //вводим его

    int *bin = new int; //динамический массив для хранения двоичных разрядов
    int i = 0;          //счетчик

    //нахожу остаток от 2, т.е. получаю двоичное значение
    while(n>0){
        bin[i] = n%2;
        n/=2;
        i++;
    }

    sort(bin, bin+i); //использую эту сортировку, т.к. не охота писать вручную
    int result=0;     //выходное значение

    //перевод в десятичную систему
    for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
        result += bin[j]*pow(2,j);
    }

    cout << result; //выводим
    delete [] bin;  //удаляем массив
    return 0;
}
```

Что я сделал: после ввода числа, я перевел его в двоичную систему. Отсортировал все 0 и 1. В итоге у нас выходить что-то вроде этого: `n = 13; { 1 1 0 1 }`, после сортировки получается такое: `{ 1 1 1 0 }`. Надеюсь вы меня поняли. Но в результате не все тесты проходят. **В чем подвох?**

Comment: Ну так а если у вас, например, 101010 - как ни сдвигайте циклически, 111000 вы не получите...

Comment: @Harry, ну так в том то и фишка, что я не сдвигаю циклически, а сортирую массив просто.. И как раз, так получается. Все работает. Но на сайте не проходит..

Comment: Хорошая логика - работает, но решение дает неверное...

Comment: А как бы нормально, что память Вы выделяете ровно под один int: `int *bin = new int;`?? А потом пишете неизвестно куда `bin[i] = n%2`.

Comment: "`int *bin = new int; //динамический массив для хранения двоичных разрядов`" - это где тут "массив"?

Comment: В условии задачи ничсего не говортся ни о какой группировке единичных битов в одну кучу (т.е. о сортировке). Задачу требуется решить для оригинального расположения битов. Зачем вы их сортируете и откуда вообще могла возникнуть такая идея?

Comment: @AnT, да вот, захотел по умничать, придумал решение..Оказалось не решение :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блин... **Циклический сдвиг**!!!

```
1010 -> 0101 -> 1010
```

Ну как вы тут получите ваше `1100`??!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int N, n, max = 0;
    cin >> N;
    int size = 0;
    n = N;
    while(n) { ++size; n >>= 1; }
    max = n = N;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        n = n>>1 | ((n&1) << (size-1));
        if (max < n) max = n;
    }
    cout << max;
}
```

Comment: Действительно! Очень спасибо. Что-то упустил такой вариант.

Comment: @Harry, _Ну как вы тут получите ваше 1100??!!_ например,если двигать единички :-)